# Swift: how to incrementally re-size a UIView by keeping a button pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

In my app the user need to re-size a `UIView` on a photographed object so that they fit together, by pressing several times a button, according to the direction of re-sizing. See this screenshot:

[image]

At the moment the user is asked to press the "plus" button many times, until the desired size but I would like the button to incrementally re-size the `UIView` by simply holding the button as pressed, as if a thread was launched which, every second for example, increases the `UIView` until the button is released. How shall I do this in Swift? Shall I create threads (if yes, how)? Shall I use a long press gesture recognizer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom button with NSTimer to detect press on button. I didn't test it but i guess it helps you:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    let updateInterval = 0.1
    var timer: NSTimer?
    var isUserPressing = false
    var updateBlock: (() -> Void)?

    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        startTimer()
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        stopTimer()
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        stopTimer()
    }

    private func startTimer() {
        isUserPressing = true
        timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: updateInterval, target: self, selector: "timerUpdated", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(self.timer!, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
    }

    private func stopTimer() {
        isUserPressing = false
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        timerUpdated() // to detect taps
    }

    private func timerUpdated() {
        updateBlock?()
    }

}
```

You can use like this:

```
let button = CustomButton()
button.updateBlock = {
    // call your update functions
}
```

Comment: Cool I like it. I'll start to write at once. Thank you!

Comment: **NOTE:** `NSTimer` will not start unless you perform `NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(self.timer!, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)` just after

Comment: I have updated the answer, can you check if it is correct?